# How come I'm getting the magnitude of the vector to be negative here?

Tags: kinematics, vectors

Note that I will be using bold letters like $\mathbf{r}$ to represent vectors throughout my question.

Say you have a body in motion whose position vector is given by $\mathbf{r} = |r|\hat{\mathbf{n}}$, where $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$ is the unit vector along $\mathbf{r}$. Now,

$$\frac{d\textbf{r}}{dt}=\mathbf{v}=|\mathbf{v}|\hat{\mathbf{n}} \tag{1}$$

where $\mathbf{v}$ is the velocity of the particle.

$$\frac{d\textbf{v}}{dt}=\mathbf{a}=|\mathbf{a}|\hat{\mathbf{n}} \tag{2}$$

where $\mathbf{a}$ is the particle's acceleration.

Say $|\mathbf{r}|=sin(t)$. Using this, we get from (1):

$$\mathbf{v}=|\mathbf{v}|\hat{\mathbf{n}}=cos(t)\hat{\mathbf{n}}$$

And from (2):

$$\mathbf{a}=|\mathbf{a}|\hat{\mathbf{n}}=-sin(t)\hat{\mathbf{n}}$$

We divide both sides by $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$, and get $|\mathbf{a}|=-sin(t)$ which will be negative for $0<t<\pi$. How can the vector's magnitude be negative? Is it wrong to divide by $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$ on both sides? Or is it wrong to consider $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$ as a constant while differentiating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some errors in your setup.

1. Your assumption $|\mathbf{r}|=\sin t$ already means that the magnitude of $\mathbf{r}$ is not positive semi-definite (it is sometimes negative), so is not a consistent assumption.
2. In general you do have to allow the direction of a vector $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$ to depend on time, so it should be differentiated in addition to the magnitude.
3. There's no reason for the position vector to point in the same direction as the velocity vector, and no reason for either to point in the same direction as the acceleration vector. So you should use a different symbol for the direction of each vector, rather than reusing the symbol $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$.
4. You can't divide an equation by a vector. If you have an equation like $a \hat{\mathbf{n}} = b \hat{\mathbf{n}}$, you can conclude that $a=b$, but the argument is not that you divide by $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$, because that is not a valid operation. Instead, you should subtract $b \hat{\mathbf{n}}$ from both sides so that the equation is $(a-b) \hat{\mathbf{n}}=0$. Then, you can dot both sides by $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$, and the equation becomes $(a-b)\hat{\mathbf{n}} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}} = a-b = 0$, which implies $a=b$.
5. It's not dimensionally correct to write $\sin(t)$. The argument of a function like sine that is not a pure power law should always be dimensionless. You should get in the practice of writing $\sin \omega t$, where $\omega=2\pi f$ is the angular frequency, and $f$ is the frequency.

Here's how I would have done this calculation. I'm not 100% sure what you meant to do for the position vector, but let's say the particle is moving in a circle of radius $r$ (an extreme example where in fact the magnitude of the displacement doesn't change and the *only* thing that needs to be differentiated is the unit vector $\hat{\mathbf{n}}(t)$)

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbf{r} &=& r \cos \omega t \hat{\mathbf{x}} + r \sin \omega t \hat{\mathbf{y}} = r \hat{\mathbf{n}}_1(t) \\
\frac{d\mathbf{r}}{dt} &=& -\omega r \sin \omega t \hat{\mathbf{x}} + \omega r \cos \omega t \hat{\mathbf{y}} = \omega r \hat{\mathbf{n}}_2(t)  \\
\frac{d^2\mathbf{r}}{dt^2} &=& - \omega^2 r \cos \omega t \hat{\mathbf{x}} - \omega^2 r \sin \omega t \hat{\mathbf{y}} =  - \omega^2 \mathbf{r} = - \omega^2 r \hat{\mathbf{n}}_1(t)
\end{eqnarray}
where $\hat{\mathbf{n}}_1(t) = \cos (\omega t) \hat{\mathbf{x}} + \sin (\omega t) \hat{\mathbf{y}}$ and $\hat{\mathbf{n}}_2(t) = - \sin(\omega t) \hat{\mathbf{x}} + \cos(\omega t)\hat{\mathbf{y}}$.
When doing the derivatives, I chose to split up the vector $\mathbf{r}$ into Cartesian components with unit vectors $\hat{\mathbf{x}}$ and $\hat{\mathbf{y}}$ (which are constant in time), rather than writing the vector as a magnitude times a direction, so that I wouldn't have to worry about differentiating the unit vector directly.

The magnitude of each of these vectors is manifestly positive
\begin{eqnarray}
|\mathbf{r}| &=& r \\
\left|\frac{d \mathbf{r}}{dt}\right| &=& \omega r \\
\left|\frac{d^2 \mathbf{r}}{dt^2}\right| &=& \omega^2 r 
\end{eqnarray}
If you do things carefully like this, you will always find the magnitude of each vector is positive, for any motion $\mathbf{r}(t)$.

Comment: So does that mean that n̂ is not a constant while being differentiated and can't be treated as such? Also, thank you for the circle example, it really helped me see why unit vectors along the x and y axes are constant but n̂ in general is not.

Comment: @AryanKomarla Correct. Usually it is easier to express $\hat{n}(t)$ in terms of constant vectors like $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$ like I did in my answer before differentiating than it is to try to directly differentiate $\hat{n}(t)$. Although, in principle, you could try to differentiate $\hat{n}(t)$ directly by subtracting $\hat{n}(t+\delta t)-\hat{n}(t)$, dividing by $\delta t$, and taking the limit $\delta t \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: thanks a lot! I can finally sleep without worrying about this

Comment: Glad to help and good night :)

Answer (score 2):

Vector division is *not* a defined concept. So stating that you "divide both sides by $\bf\hat n$" does not make sense.

If you have a vector given by ${\bf a}=-\sin\ t\ {\bf\hat n}$ then $|{\bf a}|=\sqrt{\bf a.a}=|sin\ t|$ which is *positive definite* and is therefore never less than zero.

The unit vector does "stay constant during differentiation", but also note it is of unit magnitude, and it "vanishes" due to the dot product. i.e, $${\bf\hat n\cdot \hat n}=1$$ when you calculate the magnitude of $\bf a$. Note that the magnitude of a vector is always positive.

Comment: You mean $|a|^2=\sin^2t$

Comment: no. sin(t) I had one too many $^2$

Comment: I think you mean $|a|=|\sin(t)|$ instead of $|a|=\sin(t)$.

Comment: yeah. Thanks for spotting that Andrew.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many things wrong with your formulation, but the most direct answer to your question is that *magnitude* is by definition positive, so your acceleration must also have a positive magnitude. Your definition of the position vector is problematic -- why not just start with $\mathbf{r} = \sin(t) \, \hat{r}$? Then, in Cartesian coordinates,

$$|\mathbf{r}| = |\sin(t)|; |\mathbf{v}| = |\cos(t)|; \mathrm{ and}\, |\mathbf{a}| = |\sin(t)|.$$

Note that all three quantities are non-negative throughout whatever real domain the variable $t$ lives in.

Comment: Yes, I could've started with |r|=sin(t), and avoided all confusion, but in my question, I was asking why equating the two equations gives us this "inconsistency".

Comment: The "inconsistency" is precisely because your definition of the position vector is problematic. By defining it as a magnitude, you must make sure it can *never* be negative, which you obviously failed to do.

Answer (score 0):

> Or is it wrong to consider n̂ as a constant while differentiating?

Right. You are differentiating vectors. Consider uniform circular motion. Is the direction of velocity and acceleration the same?

Acceleration shows the direction in which the object tends to move with time, not the current direction of motion.

However, the problem you are facing is that you could have taken the '-' sign along with the unit vector for acceleration, because magnitude is by definition positive.

Moreover, the concept of 'dividing by vectors' is also not very meaningful.

Comment: So $\frac{dxn̂}{dt}$ is not $n̂\frac{dx}{dt}$?

Comment: yes, you are right. Also, I must mention that @Andrew has beautifully explained it!